# Disable selecting text inside HTML element

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've added the option for the user to drag select text for copying (using the CSS property `user-select`). The problem is that it also copies text from other HTML elements:

```
<div class='select'>text</div>
<div class='no-select'>
    <b>no-select text</b>
</div>
<div class='select'>text</div>
```

So I get:

```
text

no-select text

text
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you showed all your code. i.e the bit that does the copying.

Comment: `CSS` is for styling, not behavior. This is impossible without JS, and even then the user can easily disable JS so there's no definite answer to this, thankfully.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté wrote the correct answer.

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want this behavior?

Comment: @EvanMulawski - I don't know why the OP wants to do it, but it makes sense to me that one might wish to make it easy for the user to select and copy just the main Information on a page while not selecting menus,  site-navigation links, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn - The proper way to do that is to design a print stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with the `:before` or `:after` [pseudo-elements](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/pseudo-element-before-after/):

**HTML**

```
<div class="select">text</div>
<div class="no-select">
    <strong data-text="no-select text">no-select text</strong>
</div>
<div class="select">text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.no-select > strong[data-text]:after {
    content: attr(data-text);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evanmulawski/qAFq2/)

Comment: perfect! just what i was looking for (-:

Answer (score 0):

```
.no-select{ user-select: none; }
```

You can use `user-select: none` to achieve this. Just watch for compatibility, (http://caniuse.com/user-select-none) noting that you must vendor prefix for `-ms-`, `-moz-`, and `-webkit-`.

Remember that if either 1) the user is using a browser that doesn't support this CSS, or 2) they look at the HTML source, they can still copy the text.

Comment: OP is already using this, at least that's what I can figure out from his question.